# FromHeaderAttribute doesn't work for properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to bind model property using [FromHeaderAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromheaderattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which according to documentation should work for parameter and properties.

Unfortunately, for some reason I cannot get it working for properties in PUT/POST request models:

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        [FromBody]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        // The property I want to be bound from header
        [FromHeader(Name = "Origin")] 
        public string Origin { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(
        TestModel value,
        [FromHeader] string origin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.Origin); // always empty
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value); // OK
        Console.WriteLine(origin); // OK
    }
```

Asp.Net Core App v2.2.0

Comment: I made a demo to test your code , the `FromHeader` used on the property worked well ,[here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/ERS2UEBzUKROsB8n__xgSw0BJK8JzRKZLtoY78jqL5B9aA?e=SARSZH) is my working demo , you could refer to and check the difference . If you still have the issue , could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @XueliChen, excuse me but i cannot download the demo by your link, it says I have no permissions

Comment: Here is the link to my test example: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuxYmjSB3yL8mZUg7_waLLjCrk7BiA?e=AQegik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to bind the value of Request Header to one property of the model ,  you need to configure `SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters` as `true` in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` like below :

```
services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
            options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Use the Postman with the below settings to call the post action

Add Headers :
[image]

Set the value in Body :
[image]

The screenshot of result :
[image]

Use powershell to call the post action ,change your Body like below :

```
Invoke-WebRequest `
-Method 'POST' `
-Uri "http://localhost:50112/api/values" `
-Headers @{"Pragma"="no-cache"; "Cache-Control"="no-cache"; "Origin"="http://localhost" } `
-Body ("test"|ConvertTo-Json) `
-ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: You are awesome! I think we need to make PR into existing .net documentation, to make it clear how to get this thing working. Thanks.